# TypeError: pickupList is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a currently fairly dysfunctional Javascript program that's been causing me problems. However, it throws one error that I just don't understand:

> TypeError: pickupList is not an object

```
        pickCount=objectLength(pickupList);
        pickkeys=Object.keys(pickupList);
        if (pickupList=="Fail") {
            PICKUP ="<th>PICKUP</th>";
            for (var i = 1; i <= l; i++) 
            {
                    PICKUP+= "<td id='"+((i<10) ? '0'+i : i)+'pkup'+rm_id+"'></td>";        
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var bo1;
            for (var u = 0; u < pickCount; u++) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'assets/ajax/viewAjax2event.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{competitorID:pickkeys[u],monthi:monthi,yeari:yeari},
                success:function(result)
                { 
                    bo1=JSON.parse(result);
                },              
                async:false
            });
            PICKUP+="<tr><th value="+pickkeys[u]+">"+pickupList[pickkeys[u]]+"</th>";
            for (var i = 1; i <= l; i++) 
            {

                PICKUP+= "<td class='sort' cdate1='"+((i<10) ? '0'+i : i)+"' rmID="+rm_id+" name="+pickkeys[u]+" contenteditable='"+((sit<1)? 'false' : (((monthi==monthc) && (i<day))? 'false': 'true' ))+"' onblur='editPickUp($(this).attr(\"name\"),$(this).text(),$(this).attr(\"cdate1\"),"+rm_id+")' id='"+((i<10) ? '0'+i : i)+"pickup"+u+"'>"+((i<10)? ((typeof(bo1['0'+i])!=='undefined')? bo1['0'+i]: "0") : ((typeof(bo1[i])!=='undefined')? bo1[i]: "0"))+"</td>";     
            }
            PICKUP+="</tr>";
            }
        }
```

Any ideas would be great. Frankly, I just can't see why I'm getting a TypeError. plus, it's working with latest version of firefox and chrome.

Comment: The first couple of lines suggest that it's an object, but then you have this: `pickupList=="Fail"` which suggests it's a string. So which is it?

Comment: Also you have this line in a couple of places: `for (var i = 1; i <= l; i++)`. I don't see where you've defined `l`...

Comment: It's an object, but I'm not really sure. as i didn't code this script.

Comment: I can post the whole script if you wish. let me know

Comment: We don't want you to post the whole script.  We want you to narrow down the problem.  Try reducing the script in size to create the smallest possible repro.

Comment: basically i'm getting this error as i mentioned above and it's not showing the table that i'm looking for which is located inside the .php file.